# javascript regex non-capture faster than no parenthesis at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, google-chrome, pcre

I was playing with jsperf to see if chrome optimizes the javascript regular expression by removing unnecessary non-capturing groups. However I am left baffled with an unexpected result.

## Test case

```
const anotherUnneededNonCapture = /lab(?:o)rum/
const anotherNoNonCapture = /laborum/

anotherUnneededNonCapture.exec(loremString)
anotherNoNonCapture.exec(loremString)
```

(I am testing against a lorem ipsum string where "laborum" is the last word)

## Expectation

I expected to have both "exec" tests to have the same performance if chrome does optimize the RE by removing the unnecessary non-capture group.
If the engine does not apply this optimization, i expected the normal string to be much faster, since it will not have the overhead of the unnecessary group.

## Actual result

The expression with the "unneeded" non capture group is always almost 2x faster than its counterpart!

[image]

## Link to the jsperf

https://jsperf.com/simple-quantifier-optimization-2/1

I also have tried other scenarios on different jsperf tests, all with similar results

**any ideas?** Thanks a lot, Cheers!

Comment: There was originally a `/(?:z)+/` vs. `/z+/` comparison here, right? Did it have the same performance difference on jsPerf? That one’s a little stranger to me, but I can’t reproduce it here: https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1679/0/unnecessary-non-capturing-groups

Comment: @Ryan yes same issue, i removed it to reduce confusion, the accepted answer pretty much explains it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as V8 goes, the reason for the difference has to do with an "optimization" that occurs when the regexp literal is just a plain string. In those cases, a simple string search is done (e.g. an implicit `loremString.indexOf('laborum')`) whereas this change in behavior is skipped if there are any special regexp characters in the regexp string.

So `/lab(?:o)rum/` is actually going through the regexp engine and `/laborum/` implicitly goes through an `indexOf()`-like search.

You can see this when profiling the code from node with the `--prof` and then afterward with `--prof-process` command-line options.

Comment: thank you, pretty much explains it, however, in the v8 source code, the indexof uses Boyer-Moore algorithm, shouldnt regex be used the same for its direct string replacement? O(mn) vs O(n)?

Comment: Do you know why the optimization makes it slower in this test, when `indexOf` is much faster? (I can’t save it on jsPerf because the website’s broken, but….)

Comment: @Ryan Not offhand without digging into the V8 source. I don't know that it uses the exact same code path as a literal `indexOf()`, I was mostly using that as an analogy as `indexOf()` will also use Boyer-Moore in some situations IIRC (and because it's a case sensitive search that utilizes substring indexes).

Comment: @mscdex so referring to the source code, the `atomCompile` DOES an `indexOf` search, in which `indexOf` does a  BoyerMoore(Horspool). i still cant pinpoint the reason for the huge delay..

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/46d815e7377e388dbcc81054801b35ac67f57b40/src/regexp/jsregexp.cc#L163

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/string-search.h#L59

I believe you pinpointed the main issue, but do you have any input on the reason of the delay?

Comment: In general, Boyer-Moore and its variants have some initialization overhead, such as needing to create one or more lookup tables based on the needle before a search can be done. My guess is these sorts of things are the cause of the performance degradation because they happen for every `exec()`/`indexOf()` call, which adds up.